# Get object inside object in Javascript (Vue)

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

Have a simple question that I can't figured out (I'm beginner)...

I have a object of objects:

```
monsters {
    place1: {
        monster1: { ... }
        monster2: { ... }
    }

    place2: {
        monster3: { ... }
        monster4: { ... }
    }
}
```

I want to get somethnig like that - **monsters.place1.monster1.X**

But the problem is - that I must call this.place1 (Vue.js data in components)
So - monsters.this.place1.monster1.X - not working of course

How can I get the information?

Thanks :)

Comment: You're trying to get `monsters.this.place1.monster1.X` from within the literal?

Comment: Show your actual code where you define the object and access it.

Comment: The provided information is not sufficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors#Bracket_notation) when you want to access property by variable name:

```
monsters[this.place1].monster1.X
```